# How can i implement Factory pattern without using if else or switch case in spring using annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, factory-pattern

i am learning spring..
i have gone through online resources and implemented factory pattern by using switch case...

Interface:

```
public interface Printer {
   public void print();
}
```

Implementation calsses:

```
public class Printer1 implements Printer {
   public void print() {
      System.out.println("Printer-1");
   }
}

public class Printer2 implements Printer {
       public void print() {
          System.out.println("Printer-2");
       }
 }
```

How can i load particular object based on user input?

is there any way to implement factory pattern in spring using annotations ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want some member of your class to be dynamically initialized\populated on every call to the corresponding getter, you can try the **Lookup Method Injection** as described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection). Check "3.4.6.1 Lookup method injection"

So even if the class that contains the dynamic member was created in `scope=singletone` (the default for spring bean container) every time you will access the field that has a lookup method assigned, you will get an appropriate object according to the business logic implemented inside the lookup method. In your case the `Printer` is an interface so you can easily implement the validation inside your lookup method and return a validated object.

When you configure your Main class, assign a lookup method to its member(s) that implement(s) `Printer` interface - it will be called whenever you need a new instance of the bean that implements 'Printer'.

Good luck!